# How to check a Directory to see if it has files

Tags: c#, migration

I am building a simple migration program that moves files from one folder to another folder. I am trying to figure out how to check if a directory is empty after all the files have been moved so I can build an if statement around it and if it is empty I can delete it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Hint.... there's a simple .NET method to get a list of files in a directory.

Comment: You're looking for the very aptly named `Directory` object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory

Answer (score 2):

Uno soulition is this:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("YOUR_PATH");
            if (di.GetFiles().Any())
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Any() // all files
Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path).Any() // all files and directories
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    `public boolean listOfFiles(String dir) throws IOException{
         int i =0;
         File f = new File(dir);
         File[] listOfFiles = f.listFiles();
         for (i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){
             if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
             return true;
          }
      return false;
    }`
```